# Is it possible to display keyboard shortcuts like in Unity?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Unity has this quite useful feature where you can press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key for 2-3 seconds to display all the available shortcuts:

[image]

Is there something similar in elementary OS?

Comment: I think the answer is no. Have you ever seen that feature in another desktop except Unity?

Comment: @cipricus not that I recall. I think it would make a great addition to elementary if it's not available though. There are many useful shortcuts that remain completely hidden to most users.

Comment: It is a nice feature all right. But I don't think you will get an answer other than to report on elementary OS launchpad as bug/feature request. Most probably the question will be voted for closing.

Comment: @cipricus I have no problem if it is voted for closing.

Comment: I see no reason to close this... Maybe asking is there anyway I can get this would prevent a flat "No" answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now built into elementary OS 5 Juno. Just press the Windows or Super key.

Comment: If you remap Super to show a menu, you'll also need to map the `io.elementary.shortcut-overlay` command to something in Keyboard Shortcuts to get it back.

Answer (score 3):

May not be all shortcuts, but you can review the Keyboard Shortcuts in System Settings.